# How do I make ; work like : in vimpulse?

Tags: vim, emacs, viper-mode, vimpulse

I'd like to press `;` to drop into ex mode, instead of `:`  Does anyone know how I can configure vimpulse to make this happen?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a keymap :

```
(define-key viper-vi-global-user-map (kbd ";") 'viper-ex)
```

As well, if you also use vimpulse:

```
(define-key vimpulse-visual-global-user-map (kbd ";") 'vimpulse-visual-ex)
```

Comment: Excellent!  Could you also tell me how to make : do what ; does?  (; repeats the last by-character search, such as tTfF[foo])

Comment: Use the same command, but bind (kbd ":") to `viper-repeat-find`. You can easily find what a key is binding by `CTRL-h k`